# How to handle client connections on server using signalr

Tags: connection, signalr

I have a winform desktop App.  I have referenced the signalr.client and I initiate a connection to my server. I get a connected message in my connection_stateChanged() event.

My difficulties is this: where do I trap/add a client connection in my server code? I need to add any client connections and then I was going to do put a fileSystemWatcher on a directory specific to that connectionid. Then when a files comes in (on my server) I wanted to inform my .net client of this file.  Once done I that I want my client to reconnect to receive any more messages via the same criteria.

This is what I have so far:

[ServerCode]
In Global.asax.cs page:

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<ClientListener>("echo", "/echo");
    }
```

In a class in my App_code folder:

[

```
HubName("MotionIQ")]
public class ClientListener : Hub
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void sendToSpecific(string name, string message, string to)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        Clients.Client(dic[to]).broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void Notify(string name, string id)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            Clients.Caller.differentName();
        }
        else
        {
            dic.TryAdd(name, id);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in dic)
            {
                Clients.Caller.online(entry.Key);
            }

            Clients.Others.enters(name);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
        string s;
        dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
        return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
  }
```

[In my .net c# desktop client app]

```
public void Init(bool _isLocal)
{
    var connection = new Connection("http://www.informedmotion.co.uk:12722/echo");//MotionIQ");
    connection.Received += new Action<string>(connection_Received);
    connection.StateChanged += new Action<StateChange>(connection_StateChanged);
    // Start the connection
    connection.Start().Wait();
    string line = null;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Send a message to the server
        connection.Send(line).Wait();
    }
}
void connection_StateChanged(StateChange obj)
{

}

void connection_Received(string obj)
{

}
```

Am I almost there or am I doing things completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a compelling reason to use PersistentConnection, it's recommended to use Hubs instead.

Here's a document on handling events on the Hub class:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that link.  I have recently found out that signalR resorts to long polling in not Windows 8?

Comment: To get websockets you need win8+ and .net 4.5 + IIS8 (with SignalR).. But SignalR gracefully fallbacks to other transports (SSE, foreeverframe, longpolling) if the server does not fulfill the websocket demands.